# DataError: (1406, "Data too long for column 'name' at row 1")

Tags: python, mysql, django, pycharm

I've read nearly all other posts with the same error and can't seem to find a proper solution.

In my models.py file I have this:

```
class LetsSayCups(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=65535)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

I get this error when I try to load aws mysql data into my local mysql server. I had the issue occur for another part in my models.py file, and the way I was able to work around it was by going into the my.cnf.bak file and changing the sql_mode from:

```
sql_mode=NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION,STRICT_TRANS_TABLES
```

to:

```
sql_mode=''
```

And it worked!!! Until later on I find another error. The specific error is something like this:

```
...
File "/Users/im_the_user/Desktop/my_company/my_project/load_items.py", line 122, in load_the_items
  existing_cups = Cups.objects.get_or_create(name=cups)
...
django.db.utils.DataError: (1406, "Data too long for column 'name' at row 1")
```

The above ... means things came before/after that I left out in this.

Updating my my.cnf.bak file wasnt enough, nor was making the CharField max_length to 65535. What else can I try?

Comment: use TextField instead of CharField

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that my.cfn.bak is only a backup file. I'm not sure how it worked for the first issue, but when I renamed the file to my.cfn my problem was resolved.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use a `TextField`. The `max_length` of a `CharField` should be set to 255 or less to avoid issues with DBs that store it as `VARCHAR`.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/databases/#character-fields