# Data too long for column when creating user

Tags: python, mysql, django, post, django-rest-framework

By going to

```
url(r'api/users/', views.MyUserCreate.as_view(), name='user-create'),
```

one can see DRF Browsable API

[image: DRF Create Custom User Browsable API View]

which uses MyUserCreate (in views.py)

```
class MyUserCreate(APIView):
    """ 
    Creates the user. 
    """

    def post(self, request, format='json'):
        serializer = MyUserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            MyUser.objects.create_user(
                        serializer.username,
                        serializer.password
            )
            if user:
                return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors,status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Note that it references MyUserSerializer (in serializers.py)

```
class MyUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    username = serializers.CharField(
            required=True,
            validators=[UniqueValidator(queryset=MyUser.objects.all())],
            min_length=5,
            max_length=20
            ),
    password = make_password(serializers.CharField(
            write_only=True,
            required=True,
            max_length=256
            ))

    class Meta:
        model = MyUser
        fields = ('username', 'password')

    def create_user(self, validated_data):
        password = make_password(validated_data['password'])
        user = MyUser.objects.create_user(validated_data['username'], password)
        return user
```

and MyUser (in models.py)

```
class MyUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, username, password):
        user = self.model(
            username=username
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

class MyUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    objects = MyUserManager()
    class Meta:
        # managed = False
        db_table = 'user_entity'

    user_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column='userId')
    username = models.CharField(db_column='username', unique=True, max_length=20)
    password = models.CharField(db_column='userPassword', max_length=256)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user_id) + " (%s)" % str(self.username)
```

When I post to create a user

```
{
    "username": "tiagoperes",
    "password": "test"
}
```

I get

> django.db.utils.DataError: (1406, "Data too long for column 'username'
>   at row 1")

[image: Django error Data too long for column 'username' at row 1]

Following information from other users, [checked if the column is UTF8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14318730/5675325)

[image: UTF8 column]

and doesn't make sense to [use TextField](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39420389/5675325) instead of CharField here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are passing **`serializer.username`** to create function, which is not the data you are passed via POST request, hence the error.
2. Change your method **`create_user(...)`**, to **`create(...)`** in **`MyUserSerializer`** so that, DRF will handle the function when you call the **`.save()`** method from view. (which is the DRF way)

Change your view as,

```
class MyUserCreate(APIView):

    def post(self, request, format='json'):
        serializer = MyUserSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

as well as your serializer

```
class MyUserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # rest of your code

    def create(self, validated_data):
        password = make_password(validated_data['password'])
        user = MyUser.objects.create_user(validated_data['username'], password)
        return user
```